# Having trouble initializing an SDL_Surface

Tags: c++, initialization, sdl, rectangles

I'm trying to set up something in SDL [in C++] where I can draw a one pixel big rectangle. I've got everything in my code working except my second SDL_Surface called rectangle. I'm having trouble initializing it. Here's the line where I try to initialize it:

```
rectangle = SDL_Surface(SDL_DOUBLEBUF | SDL_HWACCEL | 
                        SDL_SRCALPHA  | SDL_HWSURFACE,
                        screen->format, 1, 1, 16, NULL, clip_rect, 1);
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this and any answers you might choose to give.

Comment: What does "having trouble initializing it" mean?  It doesn't work?  You are getting some kind of error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the main problem you are having is that there is no `SDL_Surface` function.  To create a new surface, use [`SDL_CreateRGBSurface`](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_CreateRGBSurface).  Be sure to call `SDL_FreeSurface` on the returned surface after you are done with it or you will leak memory.

Additionally, I am not sure why you are creating a surface for the rectangle.  A cleaner way of drawing a solid-color rectangle is [`SDL_FillRect`](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_FillRect) without creating a new surface.